# Extract all numbers and text separetely

Tags: php

I have a text like this:

```
81. Text1

82. Text2
82.1. Some text3
82.2. Some long text goes there in two or more lines... Some more text goes here...
 
83. Text4

84. Text5
```

It has some random spacing between the lines. I'm trying to extract every single option separately. So for example my output for **82.2.** should be like this: **"82.2."** and **"Some long text goes there in two or more lines... Some more text goes here..."**.

I've already tried to do this like that:

```
$exp = explode(". ", $text);
foreach($exp as $newline) {
    
    echo explode(". ", $newline)[0];
    }
```

But probably that's not the best idea, because sometimes there's an ". " in the end of sentence.

Comment: Can you show your expected output in a better way? Right now, it is unclear whether you want strings or arrays

Comment: Can you address the answers, their accuracy and accept that suits your case the best?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track making use of `explode`:

```
$output = [];
$input = '81. Text1

82. Text2
82.1. Some text3
82.2. Some long text goes there in two or more lines... Some more text goes here...
 
83. Text4

84. Text5';

// split lines, trim any whitespace on each line and remove any that are empty
// PHP_EOL may need to be changed to how newlines are encoded in the text file
$lines = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(PHP_EOL, $input)));

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $split = explode('. ', $line);

    // The number will be the first element
    $number = trim(array_shift($split));

    // Join the rest of the elements together
    $text = implode('. ', $split);

    $output[] = [
        'number' => $number,
        'text' => $text
    ];
}

var_dump($output);
```

This yields:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(2) "81"
    ["text"]=>
    string(5) "Text1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(2) "82"
    ["text"]=>
    string(5) "Text2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(4) "82.1"
    ["text"]=>
    string(10) "Some text3"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(4) "82.2"
    ["text"]=>
    string(75) "Some long text goes there in two or more lines..Some more text goes here..."
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(2) "83"
    ["text"]=>
    string(5) "Text4"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(2) "84"
    ["text"]=>
    string(5) "Text5"
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty good solution, thank you! But there's one flaw that it keeps deleting dots in the "text". For example, if there is a sentence "One. Two" in "text" the output will be "OneTwo".

Comment: Ah, good spot, sorry about that, in the `implode`, simply replace `''` with `'. '` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `limit` parameter of the `explode` function to only get two results:

```
$str = <<<EOD
81. Text1

82. Text2
82.1. Some text3
82.2. Some long text goes there in two or more lines... Some more text goes here...
 
83. Text4

84. Text5
EOD;

foreach (explode("\n", $str) as $line) {
    if (trim($line) == "") {
        continue;
    }
    list($prefix, $text) = explode(" ", $line, 2);
    echo $prefix . " -> " . $text . "\n";
}
```

This prints:

```
81. -> Text1
82. -> Text2
82.1. -> Some text3
82.2. -> Some long text goes there in two or more lines... Some more text goes here...
83. -> Text4
84. -> Text5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple multiline regex to split the text and finish this in just 2 lines(concise code).

- Match all digits and period character from the start. Capture them in a group. `^([\d.]+)`
- Match the rest of the string in another group. `(.*)$`.
- Now, use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to match all of those lines and pass an array as a third parameter to store those matches. (say `$matches`).
- Use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to merge captured groups `1` and `2`.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

preg_match_all('/^([\d.]+)(.*)$/m', $str, $matches);
$result = array_map(fn($v1, $v2) => [ $v1, $v2] , $matches[1], $matches[2]);

print_r($result);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/57e6c)

Comment: If there are some more lines without a leading number as @fafl states in his example `Some long text goes there in two or more lines...` these would be omitted. If you alter the regular expression to `'/^([\d.]+)?(.*)$/m` they will remain.

Comment: @schmauch I agree with your case but I wouldn't wish to speculate unless OP explicitly says so.